# App doesn't seem to callback after authentication

Tags: swift, authentication, soundcloud

See i don't know if this is an error on soundcloud side or a problem with this lib
https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

So basically i'm having issues with the authentication side of things with the soundcloud api, so i'm using a webview which is programatically created and attaching this to the same view which works perfectly.

The issue is once i try to authenticate using one of the options from soundcloud either Facebook, Gmail the screen is just blank and it doesn't seem to be authenticating when using the connect with Facebook or gmail the reason why i say it isn't authenticating is because nothing is being logged in the console... and the email screen seems to be stuck as you can see in the image below... There's no callback once the authentication is done and this does work since there is output in the console when i'm testing the data being returned.

[image]

```
 func doOAuthSoundCloud(consumerKey: String, consumerSecret: String) {

    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    consumerKey,
        consumerSecret: consumerSecret,
        authorizeUrl:   authorizeUrl,
        accessTokenUrl: accessToken,
        responseType:   "code"
    )

    oauthswift.authorize_url_handler = AuthWebViewController()

    let state: String = generateStateWithLength(20) as String
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "oauthswiftexample://oauth-callback/soundcloud")!, scope: "", state: state, success: {
        credential, response, parameters in

        self.saveUserData(oauthswift,credential.oauth_token)


        }, failure: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    })
}



func saveUserData(oauthswift: OAuth2Swift, _ oauthToken: String) {
    oauthswift.client.get("https://api.soundcloud.com/me?oauth_token=\(oauthToken)",
                          success: {
                            data, response in
                            //let json = JSON(data: data)
                            print("Some data")
                            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                            let userData = JSON(dataString!)
                            print(userData)
                            print("Some response")
                            print(response)
                            print("Extra data")

        }, failure: { error in
            print(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `oauthswift` to a property instead of a local variable in the function?

Comment: @Paulw11 move what?

Comment: Sorry. Pressed enter accidentally

Comment: @Paulw11No dice still the same thing, moved the code in the function directly into the closure and its still the same